# iOS : NSFileManager copyItemAtPath is memory intensive

Tags: ios, file-io, copy, nsfilemanager

I have an app that must copy a bunch of files from disk to disk. Those files are HD raw images so they are big. I wasn't suspecting that the NSFileManager copyItemAtPath: method would actually load the content in memory to copy it to the destination path.

I had to queue this copy tasks in a queue with 4 maximum concurrent operations to avoid busting my transiting memory quota and avoid crashes but as a result, I can have to wait 1 minute to finish copying all my files ...

Is their a more efficient way to clone a file from a path to another without having to load the content in memory ?

Here is a snapshot of what's happening while profiling with instrument:

[image]

In blue: the total living allocations

In Pink: the NSFileManager copyItemAtPath: impact on memory.

http://s9.postimg.org/io3654ty7/Screen_Shot_2013_06_18_at_12_43_03_PM.png

Answer (score 0):

Similiar to the comments, but use fopen, fread, fwrite as they handle buffering for you. Also one very important point - you should set the F_NOCACHE flat on BOTH the read and write file descriptors, otherwise you will greatly increase the system memory dedicated to the disk cache, which if too large can get you killed. If you search on file copy and the flag here you will surely find code to do this in the unix or C tagged items.

Comment: Yep thank you by implementing it in pure C I managed to get more control on the memory usage. It was just curious that the default foundation does stream the file by itself :)

Comment: I am on ad now but if you look carefully, you can get the underlying file descriptor and set the flag on it too - I entered a rdar bug on the lack of this using Foundation objects but it's never been fixed.

Answer (score -1):

NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error: and copyItemAtURL:toURL:error: are the most low-level methods you can use to copy files in iOS.

So the answer is NO.

Comment: `NSFileManager` is a high-level class. There are various low-level C functions you can use to copy a file.

Comment: I also tried using C calls CopyFile() but it seems that NSFileManager is built on top of that exact same call so I've got the same issue ...

Comment: @user2498023 It all depends on how you make use of the C calls. One approach is to read/write the file in chunks. You can use a 4k buffer, as an example. Therefore your memory usage should never go over a few thousands bytes at any given time while copying a file.

Comment: @rmaddy you mean I could iterate on the source buffer and write it by chunk into it's destination path ?

Comment: @user2498023 Yes, I'm talking about using low-level functions like `fopen`, `read`, and `write`.

Comment: @smorel See something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219079/copying-contents-of-a-file-to-another-using-read-write-open